# Android: Switch between 2 Activities, 1 turn on, 1 turn off the phone

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, fullscreen, lockscreen

This is seems trivial but for the life of me I can't figure it out. Here is the scenario:

MainActivity starts with FLAG_FULLSCREEN, FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED, FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON and shows a TextView and sets SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT 1000.

In onResume I want to set a timer for 10 seconds using Thread.sleep(10000).

After 10 seconds I want to start another Activity that is similar except I clear FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON and FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON to timeout the screen in 1 second. I basically want to go back to Sleep.

Again, I set a timer for 10 seconds. Then I want to go back to MainActivity and wake the phone again and cycle.

My problems: Using Thread.sleep doesn't allow me ever see MainActivity. So I put it in a thread. Same for ResumeActivity. But then the behavior becomes random, sometimes turning on the screen, sometimes not, sometimes running onResume more then once. Sometimes Thread.sleep doesn't work but no exception.

My goal is to simply alternate between wake and sleep at an interval using a fullscreen Activity over the lock screen. WHY? (I know some will ask) I want to make a timer that doesn't stay on for the entire duration (say 1hr) but just shows the timer every few minutes to save battery life.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I found part of my problem. I guess android doesn't like threads sleeping for 10 seconds. If I set the thread.sleep to only 5 seconds then it will switch fine but not recognize the flags (the screen never turns off). So I need an idea for triggering a timed event.

UPDATE2: Ok, I discovered postDelayed to deal with timer, but seems that android cannot go to sleep in less then 15 seconds and acts weird when you have events occur during going to sleep. After setting my timer to 20 seconds everything works but won't sleep any sooner then 15 seconds. Any ideas on making android go to sleep immediately without becoming a system app?

FINAL PIECE: Any ideas on how to make

Comment: Have you had a look at the Timer class from the SDK (instead of Thread.sleep)

Comment: Sorry so long, not sure why but I never got a notification for the email. Anyway, I ended up using postDelayed as there is no timeout issues. BUT, it appears that screen timeout is hardcoded to never be less the 10 seconds even if you set it for 1.